# How do i check if visa or master card is real?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a a website that allows users to order goods.  They must pay for their shipments using COD (cash on delivery).  The User placing the order must enter a real, valid card card number (Visa or Master Card) upon order, because if he does not, the website cannot account for the service fee of using Master Card or Visa.

While researching this issue, I read about the "luhn algorithm" which can be used to determine whether a credit card number fits the correct format.  However, I need to check whether the card is legitimate, and not just a fake card number.  While researching I was able to determine that there are a lot of credit card number generators floating around the Internet.

So, what would be the best way to determine whether a credit card entered on our web page is legitimate without actually charging the credit card?

Comment: Holy ... Is it real one sentence? Without any dots? So task for you try read it on one breath now ;)

Comment: http://www.dotnetcharge.com/ using the Validate payment processor.

Comment: Are you saying you care if the card is real, but not if there is some money on it?

Comment: Test numbers exist for a reason - to allow systems to be tested without requiring real numbers (and not risking any charges). Are you trying to build an untestable system? And if not, you react as you do in any other way - if you receive a response indicating that a charge cannot proceed, then you go down that path...

Comment: @ WooCaSh: Thanks for reading my question :)

Comment: @dotnetcharge.com: thanks a lot but could you give me link or recourse for it ?

Comment: @svick: sure i want to check if card is real and its have money

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks but your i cant understand your idea isn't

Comment: @adam_salem - back at you - that's a string of words i can make no sense of. But the point I was trying to get across is that the only real measure of success is that you attempt to take a payment, and it succeeds. There's no magical pre-screening process you can apply that will ensure that a later attempt to obtain money will succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this, the approach I would use would be to actually execute the payment via some payment gateway (there are many available).  If the credit card is invalid, the payment will not clear.  I would then notify the user and give them the opportunity to pay with a different payment method, or to suspend or cancel their order.

This way you are sure to receive payment before shipping goods.

Consider changing your approach to something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's one way I know established companies use nowadays - deduct some small amount from the account, for instance $1. If everything goes fine, the card is legit. Then you can put this extra $1 on user's account, give him a discount on next payment or something.

Uhm, when I think of it, this is the only way it's done... Unless you're a banking authority, that is.